# Locking another computer in c#

Tags: c#, locking, windows

Is there a way to lock another computer through my computer by c# windows app coding? If there's a possible duplicate question please comment me the link it might help.

Comment: "define lock", what you've tried? what do you want to accomplish? Be more specific...

Comment: got the answer from some sources, just change the question can't ask anymore question coz this is my temporary account can't access my email from our office

Answer (score 1):

If you can run a background application on the machine to lock as a user with enough permissions, then yes you can definitely lock the computer remotely. I know LogMeIn has an option to lock the computer if your session times out. I'm not aware of .NET providing a mechanism to handle this remotely for you.

Comment: Why did you change the question? I was so confused.. I could not figure out how I answered the wrong question

Answer (score 0):

```
THE PERSON WHO ASKED THE QUESTION CHANGED HIS QUESTION TO PING ANOTHER COMPUTER THROUGH MY COMPUTER. ---> ORIGINAL QUESTION WAS ON HOW TO LOCK A COMPUTER THROUGH C SHARP APP.
```

The link I have provided should get you going.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/337619/Lock-computer-using-csharp-in-window-application

```
static class Program
{
    private const int WmSyscommand = 0x0112;
    private const int ScMonitorpower = 0xF170;
    private const int HwndBroadcast = 0xFFFF;
    private const int ShutOffDisplay = 2;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void LockWorkStation();
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg,
                  IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private static void TurnOffDisplay()
    {
        PostMessage((IntPtr)HwndBroadcast, (uint)WmSyscommand,
                (IntPtr)ScMonitorpower, (IntPtr)ShutOffDisplay);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        LockWorkStation();
        TurnOffDisplay();
    }
}
```